# How to make a prime number check with restart option in C?

Tags: c

I made a programme that checks if a number is a prime number or not.

The programme worked well at the start. When the programme started, I included a prime number and it gives me the correct answer. When I restart programme with the “yes” option and give it a non-prime number it also gives me the correct answer. When I restart the programme again with “yes“ option, however, none of the numbers returned are prime, even if the input is a prime number.

Could you let me know any mistakes from my code?

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
  int i=0, number, count=0;
  char answer;

  printf("\n\nthis programm check if a nummber is a prime nummber\n\n");

  do 
  {     
      printf("input a positive nummber: ");
      scanf("%d", &number);

    for (i=2; i<=number/2; i++) 
    {   


      if(number%i==0)
      {
        count=1;
        break;            
      }

    }

    if (count==0)
    { 
      printf("\n%d is  prime nummber.\n\n",number);
    }

    else if (count==1)
    { 
      printf("\n %d is not prime nummber.\n\n",number);
    }
    do
    { 
    printf("Do you want to restart the programm (J/N)? ");
    scanf(" %c", &answer);
    answer=toupper(answer);
    } while (answer!='J' && answer!='N');

  } while (answer=='J');


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is very simple: Just add `count = 0` at the start of the body of the outer `do{}while()` loop. If you forget about resetting this `count` variable you have an history effect from the loop iteration before.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
  int i=0, number=0, count=0;
  char answer;

  printf("\n\nthis programm check if a nummber is a prime nummber\n\n");

  do 
  {     
      printf("input a positive nummber: ");
      scanf("%d", &number);

    for (i=2; i<=number/2; i++) 
    {   


      if(number%i==0)
      {
        count=1;
        break;            
      }

    }

    if (count==0)
    { 
      printf("\n%d is  prime nummber.\n\n",number);
    }

    else if (count==1)
    { 
      printf("\n %d is not prime nummber.\n\n",number);
    }
    do
    { 
    printf("Do you want to restart the programm (J/N)? ");
    scanf(" %c", &answer);
    answer=toupper(answer);
    count=0;
    } while (answer!='J' && answer!='N');

  } while (answer=='J');


  return 0;
}
```

I hope it will resolve your issue